# How to catch exception in Win32 function FormatMessage

Tags: c++, winapi, exception

I have a section of code 15+ years old that formats a message from the Windows event log.  Without going into the weeds on how the Windows event log works, everything works fine as long as the message string being processed is formatted right, which is beyond our control.

The Windows function that is being used to format the message is FormatMessage.  FormatMessage is used in this case to retrieve a string resource from a .dll file, and replace parameters in the file with placeholders.  So in this case, the resource .dll file is from a 3rd party and it contains something like:

"The file %2 cannot be found".

The problem is the vendor did not supply the value of %2 in the event log, so the call to FormatMessage crashes our app, as it tries in vain to replace %2 with a parameter that isn't there.

The 32-bit build is also not affected : FormatMessage will return:

"The file (null) cannot be found"

But a 64-bit build will crash in ntdll.dll when the message string and parameters are not what FormatMessage expects.

We tried to place a try-catch block around FormatMessage, but that either didn't work, or its not constructed right.  Here is the line of code that calls FormatMessage:

```
FormatMessage(
FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE |
FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY, Hmodule, EventId, 
MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
(LPTSTR) &m_pMsg, 0, (va_list*) (LPTSTR*) Params);
```

Is there a way to surround this line of code so that either it can be trapped from triggering an exception or made to behave like its in a 32-bit world ?

Comment: Are you making the call to `FormatMessage`? Can you change that code?

Comment: Maybe with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19.aspx)? I have never used it though.

Comment: Yes, our code is calling FormatMessage, and we can change it, but there isn't much to change as the data is coming from the Windows event log (ie its known bad data, but we can't detect that its bad)

Comment: We had a try-except, but its not working, it looked like:

try
{
   FormatMessage(...etc.)
}
catch(...)
{
   m_pMsg = NULL;
}

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft's Structured Exception Handling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679270(v=vs.85).aspx .  Similar to try-catch but it is __try __except __finally.

Comment: @missioncritical Yes, I've read you used try-catch, but try-except is different, it's supposed to catch system hardware/software exceptions (which are not C++ exceptions and that's why normal try-catch doesn't work), see the link again and the example at the end :)

Comment: You need to avoid the exception in the first place. And as I understand it that is possible. This code from MSDN appears to do just that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427356.aspx

Comment: I missed that fine point, the "except" part.  Reading on that now, but the documentation is sort of, uh, lacking something.  But looking at it now - thx

Comment: David, thanks, but I read that article earlier in the day, and from what I could tell, it does not do anything that we are not doing now.  The only way to avoid a crash is to first have FormatMessage read the message file using the FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS parameter, then examine how many insert strings are needed, compare that to the va_list received earlier when reading the log to see if its 'OK' to then call FormatMessage a second time and have it do the substitutions.  The problem with that approach is it would kill performance, since 99.99% of the messages are formatted correctly.

Comment: user2802841 / cup:

__try and __except worked !.  In the __except section, I even recalled the function using the FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS so that I can at least show the user the malformed message string.

Thanks a ton

Comment: @mission I believe that code already does that. Is message formatting the performance bottleneck in your app?